# Self in Active Record Callback returning nil for associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to create a callback that sends my ActionCable broadcast when an associated record is created.

```
 after_save :broadcast_connection_open_to_room
 before_destroy :broadcast_connection_close_to_room

 private
   def broadcast_connection_close_to_room
     ActionCable.server.broadcast(
       'room_' + self.room_id.to_s,
       state: "exit",
       connection_id: self.id,
     )
   end

   def broadcast_connection_open_to_room
     ActionCable.server.broadcast(
       'room_' + self.room_id.to_s,
       state: "enter",
       connection_id: self.id,
       html: ApplicationController.render(partial: "connections/connection", locals: {connection: self})
     )
   end
```

My after-destroy is working as expected.  However when the after_save runs my partial is throwing ***undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass*** when it try to render my partial.

```
%li.list-group-item{id: "connection_" + connection.id.to_s}
 %h4.list-group-item-heading.text-left= connection.user.username 
 %div.text-left
   .pull-right.vcenter
     %span Mute Player
     %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-volume-off
```

Connection itself isn't nil.  But when the partial references the associated user record it gets into trouble.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you destroyed the connection object itself so when active record tries to query for the associated user, its actually not found. Why dont you try passing the user as well into the partial.

Something like:

```
...locals: {connection: self, user: self.user}
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but it's producing the same result.

Comment: How about `%h4.list-group-item-heading.text-left= User.find(connection.user_id).username`?